# WPF BitmapImage loaded from Base64String not showing

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, signalr

I am trying to make a screen sharing application. As a first step I am trying to share the host's screen using screenshots.
In order to connect the host with the client, I am using SignalR. After the authentication is done, I am starting a timer for the host that will take a screenshot when it elapses. The screenshot code is as follows:

```
public static byte[] TakeScreenshot(int width = 0, int height = 0)
    {
        var bmp = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                           PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
        var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
        gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

        if (width != 0 && height != 0)
            bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, new Size(width, height));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

The timer's elapsed handler:

```
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bytes = ImageHelper.TakeScreenshot();
        string imageString = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        Communicator.Instance.Produce(new BroadcastDataComm() { DataType = DataType.Image, Data = imageString }, _connectedHost);
    }
```

The screenshot will be received as byte array then converted to Base64String in order to broadcast it through SignalR. When the authentication is done I am creating a new WPF window (in the parent Xaml.cs class) and show it, then, all the clients authenticated to the host will receive the produced message and send the base64string to the new window:

```
ScreenSharingWindow _window = new ScreenSharingWindow();
    private void AuthenticateSuccess(string id)
    {
        ConnectionId = $"Connected to: {id}";
        _connectedHost = id;
        Dispatcher.Invoke(() => _window.Show());
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void ScreenshotReceived(BroadcastDataComm ss)
    {
        if (!(ss.Data is string imgString))
            return;


        Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> _window.ImageData = imgString);
    }
```

Finally, I am creating a Bitmap object from the string using those 2 properties in the new window and using a converter on that object so I can bind the XAML's Image control to it:

```
    private Bitmap _image;
    public Bitmap Image
    {
        get => _image;
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            Image.Save(@"C:\Users\roudy\Desktop\test.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }

    private string _imageData;
    public string ImageData
    {
        get => _imageData;
        set
        {
            _imageData = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();

            var ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(ImageData));
            Image = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
    }
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is Bitmap bmp)
            return ImageSourceFromBitmap(bmp);
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);

    public BitmapSource ImageSourceFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        try
        {
            var ret = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
            return ret;
        }
        finally { DeleteObject(handle); }
    }
}
```

I have added Image.Save(...) in the property's setter to make sure that the image is received as expected and it's working properly, and I can see the image correctly updating when I check it's thumbnail in the desktop. But for some reason, it just refuses to show in the WPF control. I've tried to create a bitmap from file and it worked fine so the binding and converter is correct.

Why won't the Image show on the control ?
Thank you.

EDIT: In order to check if the Binding is correct, I just created the bitmap from the new window's constructor and commented out the part where the parent window was setting the property. The new handler in the parent window would be:

```
private void ScreenshotReceived(BroadcastDataComm ss)
    {
        if (!(ss.Data is string imgString))
            return;


        //Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> _window.ImageData = imgString);
    }
```

and the new window's constructor:

```
public ScreenSharingWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\roudy\Desktop\SaveIcon.png");
    }
```

Note: When I try to load the bitmap from file from within "ImageData" property it also doesn't work so it seems like it's a threading issue, when it's changed from the parent window (through SignalR handler) it doesn't show.

Comment: Add the code that shows what you did when the bitmap was loaded from the file, so that the community can compare the implementations.

Comment: This is totally confusing. Where do you eventually load a BitmapImage from a base64 string? When you have a MemoryStream over a byte array converted from a base64 string, you could directly pass that to the StreamSource property of a BitmapImage.

Comment: @Clemens sorry if it’s not clear, this is my first post here. I am converting the string into a bitmap using byte[]->MemoryStream-> Bitmap then bind an Image’s source to the bitmap using a converter. I’ve used a converter from “gdi32.dll”

Comment: @Clemens i think i’ve already tried your approach, i’ve honestly tried a dozens of approaches and none worked. Anyway, thank you for pointing it out i will try it again tomorrow morning and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from SignalR. I am running 2 instances of the same project, the screenshot was being sent to the host instead of the client and the client needed it to create a new window with it, which results in the image being blank. Thank you @Clemens for making it easier to debug without needing converters and more complications.